# Silverlight ResourceDictionary problem

Tags: silverlight, resourcedictionary

I have reports.xaml page where I have defined some local resources.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.Namespace;component/Resources/Converters.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.Namespace;component/Resources/GlobResources.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.Namespace;component/Resources/ReportingResources.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the same reports.xaml file I have a content control like so...

```
<ContentControl
Content="{Binding}"
ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource reportTemplateSelector}, Path=CurrReportType}"
Margin="0"
/>
```

Now in my converter I load the ReportingResources.xaml resource file with the following lines of code

```
ResourceDictionary reportTemplate = new ResourceDictionary();
reportTemplate.Source = new Uri("/My.Namespace;component/Resources/ReportingResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
template = reportTemplate[Report_Style] as DataTemplate;
return template;
```

"Report_Style" will actually be a variable that will get set in Convert method of the reportTemplateSelector converter before the above lines get called.

The problem here is that ReportingResources.xaml is dependent on the GlobResources.xaml resource file for some other content. How do I make the content from GlobResources.xaml  available to the ReportingResources.xaml file in the lines of code above?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: I'm guessing this is a library you are building on basis that your resource dictionaries are added as Resource rather than Content.  Is that correct?  Its an important detail because in an application you would use the App.xaml to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried....

A resource file can merge other resource files:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceB.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Name="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Taken from [Silverlight 3,0 Split styles and templates into different files and merge resources](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/03/31/silverlight-3-0-split-style-and-template-into-different-files-and-merge-resources.aspx)